# What does this line of code means in C++ class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, destructor

I stumbled upon this piece of code while I was reviewing a repo and couldn't find any reference on the internet.

What exactly does it? I assume it specify the default constructor and destructor to be used. But why bother writing this if the default constructor and destructor are implicitely used if there is no custom one?

```
 foo::foo() = default
 foo::~foo() = default
```

### foo.h

```
class foo
{
public:

    foo();
    
    ~foo();

    void program();

};
```

### foo.cpp

```
foo::foo() = default;
foo::~foo() = default;
```

Comment: This tells the compiler (explicitly) to use its generated default implementations for default constructor `foo()` and destructor `~foo()`. I've never seen the `= default` outside of class declaration but `g++` seems to have no complaints about this: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c03276e5e7db3306)

Comment: It tells to use the compiler generated default version of `foo::foo()` and `foo::~foo()` in modern c++

Comment: It’s not an example of its being useful, it’s an example of the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply tells the compiler to use its default generated variants of the constructor and destructor.

Note that you don't need to put the constructors and destructors in the source file, you can have those "defaultings" in the header file as well:

```
class foo
{
public:

    // Use compiler-generated default implementation    
    foo() = default;
    
    // Use compiler-generated default implementation    
    ~foo() = default;

    void program();

};
```

See constructors 3 and 5 in [this default constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), as well as destructor 3 in [this destructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).

Comment: A bit confusion for me, what do you mean by - *generated variants of the constructor and destructor*?

Comment: @RohanBari For any class without any declared constructor, the compiler will automatically generate a default-constructor. There are cases that prohibits this automatic generation (due to the rules of C++), but then one can explicitly tell the compiler to generate such a default constructor anyway by using the `= default` syntax.

Comment: same comment as on the other answer. In this context the link to default constructors can be slightly misleading because a default constructor is not necessarily a compiler generated one, though after reading the link that could become clear

Comment: Note that `=default` outside vs inside the class changes the properties of the class.

Answer (score 4):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

```
class_name() = default ;    (4) (since C++11)
```

4. Defaulted default constructor: the compiler will define the implicit default constructor even if other constructors are present.

`class_name :: class_name ( ) = default ; (5) (since C++11)`

5. Defaulted default constructor outside of class definition (the class must contain a declaration (1)). Such constructor is treated as user-provided (see below and value initialization).

Comment: That is a bit misleading, because the compiler generated constructor is a default constructor, but a default constructor is not necessarily a compiler provided one. There is an unfortunaty subtle difference between "default" and `default`